# Bulk move files back to where they came from

Tags: files, data-recovery, move

**What happened**

I'm in quite a mess right now after having clamscan scan over my windows part of the system and move all found files (which apparently includes PUA's) to a directory on another drive. Being the idiot I am, I did not log the operation, and therefore do not know where all the files came from.

The exact command I ran was

```
sudo clamscan -r -z --move=/tmp/infected/ --detect-pua=yes --partition-intersection=yes -i
```

**What now**

Now I am stuck with a directory of 532 files that I have to move back, having no clue where most of them came from, and have to move each of them back to repair the applications using them.

**What I want**

Is it possible to track these file move operations after they happened to recover my data to its origin?

Comment: If you've already discarded the output from the command you ran, you have no record of its operation. By default `clamscan` writes only to _stdout_.

Comment: I was able to rescue some last parts of the output, however most of it was lost/discarded after exceeding the buffer.

Comment: if you have/had locate/updatedb running, you could search it

Comment: @JeffSchaller that's a really good idea. @ionree if you have or had `locate` configured and working, switch off and disable the `cron` entry that updates its database. Now. Before it gets overwritten.

Comment: I like the idea, but sadly I'm out of luck. These files were on an NTFS drive mounted to /media and not indexed by locate. I guess I will just fix as problems occur, and hope that most software will tell me what missing file caused the error.

Comment: I'm out of my depth here, but maybe the "Microsoft Indexing Service" on the hosting computer has something you can search with?

Comment: Unfortunately, indexing was turned off a long time ago on that machine